# Pulling stats from array in an interface?

Tags: java

Being completely and totally honest here, I have no idea how to phrase my question, and have perused the interwebs for hours to find it, but it looks like the kind of thing that isn't all too common but can be solved by looking at my code.

```
public class Stats implements BasesGalore {


private static String getCharacterClass(int a, int d, int m, int s) {
    if (a == 0 && d == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0) {return "villager";}
    if (a == 1 && d == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0) {return "fighter";}
    if (a == 0 && d == 1 && m == 0 && s == 0) {return "guard";}
    if (a == 0 && d == 0 && m == 1 && s == 0) {return "spellcaster";}
    if (a == 0 && d == 0 && m == 0 && s == 1) {return "athlete";}
    if (a == 1 && d == 1 && m == 0 && s == 0) {return "knight";}
    if (a == 1 && d == 0 && m == 1 && s == 0) {return "spellsword";}
    if (a == 1 && d == 0 && m == 0 && s == 1) {return "martial_artist";}
    if (a == 0 && d == 1 && m == 1 && s == 0) {return "cleric";}
    if (a == 0 && d == 1 && m == 0 && s == 1) {return "escapist";}
    if (a == 0 && d == 0 && m == 1 && s == 1) {return "expediter";}
    if (a == 2 && d == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0) {return "slayer";}
    if (a == 0 && d == 2 && m == 0 && s == 0) {return "defender";}
    if (a == 0 && d == 0 && m == 2 && s == 0) {return "magician";}
    if (a == 0 && d == 0 && m == 0 && s == 2) {return "guerrilla";}
    else return "villager";
}

private static int fa = 0;
private static int fd = 0;
private static int fm = 0;
private static int fs = 0;

private static int BaseHP = getCharacterClass(fa, fd, fm, fs)[0]; // Base stats for the character's class
```

My problem here is on the final line. I'm trying to pull from an interface loaded with all the base stats for my characters (each class has its own specific array with its stats). I'm trying to call getCharacterClass to find the character's class, then look up its base stat through the array.

Here's a bit of the interface:

```
public interface BasesGalore {

String[] classes = {
        "villager",
        "fighter", "guard", "spellcaster", "athlete",
        "knight", "spellsword", "martial_artist", "cleric", "escapist", "expediter", "slayer", "defender", "magician", "guerrilla"
};

int[] villager = {
        50, 50, 50, 50, 50 // 50
};

int[] fighter = {
        60, 70, 50, 35, 35 // 50
};

int[] guard = {
        80, 50, 80, 20, 40 // 54
};

int[] spellcaster = {
        65, 20, 15, 105, 60 // 53
};

int[] athlete = {
        65, 50, 50, 20, 80 // 53
};

int[] knight = {
        80, 70, 50, 35, 35 //
};
```

Thanks in advance and i'm truly sorry if absolutely none of it makes sense,
NitroDragon523

Comment: `getCharacterClass()` returns a `String`. What is this interface you are talking about?

Comment: Like @John3136 said, `getCharacterClass()` returns a `String` but your are trying to cast it to an `int`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @John3136 I have an interface with my character's stats in arrays. One array per character.

Comment: @NitroDragon523 Why mention it? It doesn't seem to be part of your question - unless you should be using the class name to lookup an interface implementation...

Comment: @John3136 I'm pretty sure that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: What I'm ultimately looking for is how to change getCharacterClass(fa, fd, fm, fs)[0] into (class name)[0]. The getCharacterClass returns a String. I want to use the String it returns to correspond with my interface.

Comment: You need `BasesGalore` to provide a method like `int[] getStats(String name)`. But even better would be a `Base` class that holds the stats and `BasesGalore` could just be a map of "name->instance"

Comment: @John3136 How would I do that?

Comment: You should think a bit first, `getCharacterClass` return a `String` that you tried to read like an array to declare an `int`... So here nothing make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be honest, OO is there for you.

First, you should not generate arrays for the stats but instance of a `BaseCharacter`.

```
public class BaseCharacter{
    private String name; //just to have his name
    private int stat1; //to rename later
    private int stat2; //to rename later
    ...
    private int statX; //to rename later

    public BaseCharacter(String name, int stat1, int stat2, ..., int statX){
        this.name = name;
        this.stat1 = stat1;
        this.stat2 = stat2;
        ...
        this.statX = statX;
    }

    // add getter (and setter if the stats can be modify)
}
```

Then, in the interface, the `String[]` should become a `BaseCharacter[]`.

```
interface BasesGalore {

    static final BaseCharacter[] characters = {
        new BaseCharacter("Villager",  50, 50, 50, 50, 50),
        new BaseCharacter("Fighter",  60, 70, 50, 35, 35),
        ...
    };

    ...
}
```

Then, you have some choice to get the correct instance, one, since this array is in the interface, you could list some constant with the index of each character (only intersting if there is not to many characters)

```
static final int VILLAGER = 0;
static final int FIGHTER = 1;

public static BaseCharacter getCharacter(int index){
    return characters[index];
}
```

This would be used like

```
BasesGalore.getCharacter(BasesGalore.FIGHTER);
```

Or you use the names of each instance to find it, this is better if you want to be able to update the character list dynamicly.

```
public static BaseCharacter getCharacter(String name);
```

Here, you can use a simply loop to find the character with the similar name. Be aware that this could return null.

Comment: Thank you so much—this is awesome.

Comment: If this help you, don't hesitate to accept this answer to close the question. Or wait for more answers if you want of course.

Comment: @NitroDragon523 I suggest you follow some tutorial about Object Oriented programming, this will help you in the future

Comment: Yeah, this is a concept I've struggled with a little bit. Thanks again